# use mock server in testing flask app using pytest

Tags: python, flask, mocking, pytest

**tl;dr**
I am looking for the best practice for testing a flask app which uses external APIs under its routes, and probably this is where I have to simulate the external APIs using mock servers in the testing stage.

---

Ok, all I have got searching `pytest-mock` and similar packages is that I can mock a function and have the results prepared for test assertions. But unfortunately I cannot find a best-practice explanation for my situation:

I have a flask app, under some of the routes of which I use external APIs and I want to use mock servers replacing those real external API URLs. I have come to two apparently fair solutions:

**Using test URLs when testing**

What I have got so far is that I can set different URLs dynamically by `app.config` so that in my `conftest.py` I can invoke using test URLs, and in reality, my app will be launched by the main URLs. Now my question here is how I can run a mock server *automatically* in the `pytest fixture` setup stage to occupy the test URLs localhost ports. I said automatically because I can naively run a manual mock app in background myself, which is silly and useless for automated testing purposes

**Using a mock function instead of sending the request to the main URL**

I have realized that I can setup a mocker which is a function returning my desired value, and use it alongside calling my to-be-tested app. but the point is I want to use the mock *inside* my app, not comparing the returning value with a mock generated value

So where am I and what should I do?!

Here is a sample:

My flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    value = request.args.get('dummy_val')

    # using external APIs
    # This is where I need mock server
    output = requests.get(
         'http://external.api/some/url',
         params={'val':value}
    )
    return output*2
```

my test file:

```
def test_can_double_value(test_client):
    result = test_client('/test', query_string={'dummy_val':'foo'})
    # test if status code == 200
    # test if string equals to something
    # blah blah blah
```

Comment: If you want to mock `requests`, you could use [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses).

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is the behavior of the `@response.activate`? if I decorate my test function, will my flask function also get the effect?

Comment: It would be pretty pointless if it only applied to requests made from the test function, no? I'd recommend *trying it out* and seeing whether it suits your purpose.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is successful if I add `responses` to the test itself. any idea how to make a fixture which enables `responses` feature? decorating fixture doesn't work

Comment: There's a section in the readme specifically on using responses as a pytest fixture, did you try that?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I did it, but I want to do the `response.add` in my fixture function, not test function. I did it by adding `response.add` in `fixture` and just enable the test function by response decorator and it apparently works. Thanks for the life saving help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) I now am aware that this can be done using [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) library. Now if we want to mock an API in the fixture, it can be done as follows:

in `conftest.py`

```
import response
from pytest import fixture

@fixture
def client():
    # add response
    responses.add(responses.GET,
        'http://mock.api/v',
        json={'key': 'value'},
        status=200
    )
    # do fixture stuff -> here it is yielding app test client
    app.config['TESTING'] = True
    client = app.test_client() 

    yield client
```

in `test_module.py`

```
import response

@response.activate
def test_can_connect(client):
    result = client.get('/test')
    assert result.status_code == 200
```

and in `app.py`

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    res = requests.get('http://mock.api/v')
    # blah blah
```

**Comment** in `responses` documentation it is suggested that we add a response in the test function. But as I wanted to add it in a fixture, this is how I did it.

Comment: That seems deeply suspect. Firstly, you have some typos. But more importantly the fixture should be providing the mock handler, not the client itself (you can have a second fixture for that). Secondly, explicitly telling the code it's being tested seems like a very bad idea - you end up testing the test branches rather than the production code. Finally, the point of setting the response in the test rather than the fixture is that: 1. you can have different responses in different tests (e.g. to ensure that errors and successes are both handled correctly); and 2. the test can be read on its own.

Comment: it is right that the response can be added in a new fixture, but I did not experience any limit in setting the response in the test client fixture... I thought it would be a good idea to add the response in a fixture because many test functions are to be tested with mock servers, and I don't want to repeat myself. Am I right?

Comment: Your comment about explicitly telling the main code is probably because I used the 'mock.api/v' url in my flask app, but it was only a figure of speech! I meant any URL that is real and I wanted to mock it in the test stage by pytest

Comment: There is a limit, it's that you can't change the response anywhere. If you have one single response that's used in most of your test cases, by all means make that a specific fixture, but in general you don't need that many tests for one specific upstream response. And by *"explicitly telling the code"* I meant `app.config['TESTING'] = True`; apparently that's to [*"disable the error catching during request handling"*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/), so if you don't have conditionals in your own code based on it that's probably not a problem.

Comment: Regarding the response adding in the fixture, you are right about the area of effect of the fixture, however, I may be able to control it by setting the scope of the fixture to `function` and do the `response.remove` in teardown stage of the fixture. Generally speaking, I did it because I wanted the same connection over the majority of the tests... and about the `app.config` part, you are right, it is a situation to be careful about. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to answer, but I have stumbled across the same problem just now.
Previous answers seems to be solving the problem in practice, but if you think about your problem in theory, I think you have 2 options.

Either:

- mock the interface on 'requests' level, which works fine, but exposes your test code to implementation detail, as suggested before me
- create adapters for these services in your code, and replace them with your mocks/stubs in your test code.
- using a test fixture, you can start your own webserver for the process using the code from this gist:
  https://gist.github.com/eruvanos/f6f62edb368a20aaa880e12976620db8

The benefit of the last approach is quite straightforward. You can leave your code as is when testing, no stubbing/mocking, and create the mocks outside your system, where you have free control over mocks, and don't have to worry about actual implementation (like before, you have to KNOW that the service is called via requests).